# centrioles in primitive plants, algae and fungi

Tags: botany, mycology

Do these groups of organizms lack centrioles or possess?

1. Red algae (yes?)
2. Diatoms (no?)
3. Yest (no?)
4. Chydtridiomycetes (no?)
5. Liverworths (yes?)
6. Hornwoths (yes?)
   7.Zygomycetes (no?)
   Cannot find exact answers, complicated case. Need help.

Comment: this may get closed for being more than one question but until then , yes for hornworts. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3240993/